# How to count a Column data using join over 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have three tables

```
tbl_product 
item_id | item_name

company_details
v_id | item_id | company_name

user_ratings 
r_id | rate | v_id
```

I want to count the rate and also get the rate of the company. Here is my query

```
SELECT  company_details.v_id,
        company_details.company_name,
        COUNT(user_ratings.rate) as vote,
        user_ratings.rate,
        tbl_product.item_name
FROM    company_details
LEFT JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_product.item_id = company_details.item_id
LEFT JOIN user_ratings ON user_ratings.v_id = company_details.v_id
GROUP BY company_details.v_id, user_ratings.rate
```

This is Whts i am Getting after this query:

```
v_id  company_name           vote  rate  item_name  
1     The Oberoi Udaivilas   1     4     5 Star Hotels  
1     The Oberoi Udaivilas   1     5     5 Star Hotels  
2     The Taj Mahal Palace   2     5     4 Star Hotels  
3     Rambagh Palace         1     5     3 Star Hotels  
4     Taj Lake Palace        1     5     5 Star Hotels  
5     Windflower Hall        1     3     2 Star Hotels  
5     Windflower Hall        1     5     2 Star Hotels  
6     Leela Palace Kempinski 0     n     4 Star Hotels  
7     Umaid Bhawan Palace    0     n     4 Star Hotels  
8     Hotel Ratan Vilas      0     n     4 Star Hotels  
9     The Leela Palace       0     n     4 Star Hotels  
10    The Imperial Hotel     0     n     3 Star Hotels
```

You can see vote column is not counting.

This is what I am expecting

```
v_id  company_name          vote  rate  item_name   
1     The Oberoi Udaivilas  2     5     5 Star Hotels   
2     The Taj Mahal Palace  2     5     4 Star Hotels
```

But this query is not counting the rate from `user_ratings` table, because of I also want to get the rate, if I remove the `user_ratings.rate` from `select` clause, then this query works, but when I add the `user_ratings.rate` in the `select` clause, then this query is not counting the rates as(vote), and it is returning as one rows in every count.

Comment: You really should provide sample input and expected output, because from your description it's not clear at all what you're asking for

Comment: If, as in your output, you want it grouped by company, it should be in your group by clause.

Comment: Still i am getting the same result

Answer (score 1):

You should remove *user_ratings.rate* from group by clause and add *tbl_product.item_name*.

```
SELECT
    company_details.v_id,
    company_details.company_name,
    tbl_product.item_name,
    COUNT(user_ratings.rate) as vote,
    avg(user_ratings.rate) as rate
FROM
    company_details
    LEFT JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_product.item_id = company_details.item_id
    LEFT JOIN user_ratings ON user_ratings.v_id = company_details.v_id
GROUP BY company_details.v_id, company_details.company_name, tbl_product.item_name;
```

Comment: You should provide some context to your answer, as code-only answers make understanding what was wrong and what canged harder

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that your query is only missing an aggregation on the `rate` column, and from the expected output I'd say it's a `max`. You also should fix your `group by`. Try this one

```
SELECT  company_details.v_id,
        company_details.company_name,
        COUNT(user_ratings.rate) as vote,
        MAX(user_ratings.rate) as rate,
        tbl_product.item_name
FROM    company_details
LEFT JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_product.item_id = company_details.item_id
LEFT JOIN user_ratings ON user_ratings.v_id = company_details.v_id
GROUP BY company_details.v_id,
         company_details.company_name,
         tbl_product.item_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Query and result are both correct. Look at the rate

Answer (score 0):

you can try this query it will return your exactly output according to your given 3 tables.

```
"select c.v_id , c.company_name , u.rate , p.item_name from company_details c  join  tbl_product p on p.item_id = c.item_id  join user_details u on c.v_id = u.v_id group by c.company_name ";
```